# How to speed up write using MMC in U-Boot?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sd-card, u-boot

I'm trying to use U-Boot to copy a big (2 GiB) image from the network to the SD card. This image is a filesystem; hence I'm using the mmc subsystem.

I created many chunks of this image, 64 MiB each, so the process goes like this:

1. Download next chunk using TFTP
2. Write sub-chunks to the sd card using mmc
3. Go to 1

The problem is that writing to the sd card is really slow. It takes several minutes for a chunk of 4 MiB. I have tried with different sizes and it is all the same -- pretty slow.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 and Samsung micro SD cards (class 10).

The command I use for writing is like:

`mmc write 0x1600000 0xFF000 0x02`

For me, this means, taking from the memory address `0x1600000`, read `0x02` blocks of `512 bytes` and write them to the sd card starting at block `0xFF000`

Am I using the wrong command? Is there a way to speed up the process? The U-Boot driver for is slow?

Note: Yesterday night I copied an image of 1.3 GiB. It took 16 hours.

Editing:
Git repository git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git

commit ae765f3a8243faa39d4a32ba2baede638e40c768

Compilation:
`make rpi_2_defconfig`
`make all`

Comment: Can you provide link to U-Boot version you are using? We need link to git repo, branch name and name of config file you are using for building U-Boot, so we can check MMC driver and its settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this writing, the current release of U-Boot (v2016.03) has the dcache disabled on RPi 2.  So things are in fact just slow.  Also there are currently patches being reviewed which would enable the dcache and speed this up.  There's expected to be at least one more version of these patches due to a problem with the LCD one but more testers are welcome and encouraged.  You can get the current series (v2) here:
https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/uboot/list/?submitter=1212&state=7&q=v2&delegate=3651
 and note that the patch that is 0/5 is the fix for the LCD issue and thus why I'm expected a clean v3 to be submitted.

I am hopeful that the changes will be able to be merged for the v2016.05 release.

Comment: I will check the patch, if it works I will accept the answer. In fact, reading here and there I though this was the problem, but I didn't know how to fi it myself.

Comment: Alexander respun the patches in question and I've since merged the series into master, so confirmation that top of tree fixes your problem is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that solved the issue. It went from 200 KBit/sec to 7.1 MBit/Sec. Thanks.